# sudo apt update, stuck 0% connecting

Tags: apt

When I do sudo apt update I keep getting stuck in the line below:

```
0% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1360:8001::21)]
```

Is there any problem with ipv6 resolution in Ubuntu? Is there a way to force ipv4 in case this is the problem ? (maybe my router is not so smart, I don't know).

Ping output:

```
ping6 2001:67c:1360:8001::21
PING 2001:67c:1360:8001::21(2001:67c:1360:8001::21) 56 data bytes
^C
--- 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11000ms
```

Traceroute output:

```
 traceroute6  2001:67c:1360:8001::21traceroute to 2001:67c:1360:8001::21
 , 30 hops max, 24 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks! I didn't knew there was a Best Server option! Trying it here...

Comment: @ScottStensland , it worked! Can you write an answer?

Comment: You can go to Network setting and ignore IPv6 with network that you connected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From time to time ... like after traveling to a new location ... its good to update your locally fastest ubuntu repo server by running this probe

```
System Settings -> 
Software & Updates -> 
Download from -> 
Other -> 
Select Best Server
```

Comment: Why are you delete the comment?

Comment: How do you do this from the CLI?

Answer (score 20):

Adding `-o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true` after your `apt-get` command will force IPv4 connectivity.

For a permanent fix, create a file called  `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4` and add the following line to it:

```
Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";
```